# How to pause and resume Screen for specified time range (schedule)

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I use linux `screen` command to execute a background script on my server. The script needs to run everyday but within a certain time range (7 am to 9 pm). As of now, I am manually exiting the `screen` (by using `ctrl+c` followed by `exit` command) everyday at 9 pm and re creating the `screen` (by using `screen -S <NAME>`) at 7 am of the following day.

Is there a way to make `screen` 'automatically' sleep between 9 pm and 7 am? (So that I need not intervene manually everyday.)

Comment: This sounds like a perfect case for `man crontab`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use screen, but if you insist, you can do it like this:

`0 7 * * * some_user sh -c 'screen -d -m -S 7to9am -s /usr/local/bin/the_script.sh ; sleep 2h ; screen -X -S 7to9am quit'`

At the end of `/etc/crontab`

The *correct* way to do to this would be without screen:
`0 7 * * * some_user timeout 2h /usr/local/bin/the_script.sh`